# Laptop accessories for mobile warrior (light power adapter & case/bag)

Tags: laptop, power-supply, case

Lugging my X301 between work and home, I realized my laptop's accessories weigh more than the laptop itself!

I'm ordering a 2nd AC power adapter so I don't even have to carry one at all, but I may as well get the lightest one possible. My X301 came with a pretty svelt 65W power adapter, but **can anyone suggest a lighter power adapter or confirm the weights I've found below?**

```
mass vol     dimensions  W   Model
---- ------- ----------- --- -------------------
210g 149cm^3 108x46x30mm 65W Coolermaster [NA 65]
244g 189cm^3 140x75x18mm 65W ThermalTake [ADP65W0001]
260g 130cm^3 104x43x29mm 65W Lenovo (came with X301)
326g 198cm^3 145x76x18mm 95W Coolermaster [SNA 95]
330g 180cm^3 150x60x20mm 90W Kensington USB [K38030US]
```

Apple's 60W power adapter seems much smaller/lighter than the PC products listed above, so I think a better PC power adapter could exist. **There are much smaller 45W "netbook" adapters, but are these too weak for my X301?** I would not mind if it just meant the battery couldn't charge while the laptop was on, but I am afraid there will be worse consequences.

Also, I have decided to swap my Logitech Kinetik briefcase for a [Tom Bihn Ristretto](http://www.tombihn.com/page/001/PROD/MACBOOKAIR/TB0223). Less protection, but much lighter, less bulky, and easier to carry. **Any suggestions for better laptop cases/bags?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the Coolermaster [NA 65].

- Despite the difference in spec'ed mass, I can barely tell the difference between the original Lenovo one that came with my laptop. The difference probably comes down to how manufacturers weigh them (with/without cord, etc)
- The only real differences are in the cables. The Coolermaster one comes with tips for multiple makes of laptops and they are angled at 90 degrees. I actually prefer the Lenovo unangled design: it fits more snugly and I feel it brushing my lap less.
- I was able to personally physically handle the other candidates, but they all felt heavier and bulkier.

Also the Ristretto bag is *awesome*. Not as much padding/room as my Kinetik, but sufficient. The design is much, much more comfortable to carry around and convenient to quickly access. I take the Ristretto on short commutes to work, and the Kinetik on longer trips (where I need to stow the laptop in an overhead bin, or something).